# Bootstrap fluid thumbnails within a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails, fluid-layout

I'm trying to get my thumbnails evenly spaced within a row.  Each of them is a span2, with a 240x240 image, and the row is span12.  So when I have 6, it looks perfect.  When I have 5, it just leaves the last 2 spans blank.  What should I do so that it automatically evenly spaces the span2 thumbnails so that it takes up the entire row with equal spacing between them?

Added code:

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <ul class="thumbnails">
     <li class="span2">
       <a href="#edithotelModal" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240" alt="">
        <h3>Room 1</h3>
        <p> <%= Forgery(:lorem_ipsum).words(20) %></p>
         </a>
     </li>

     <li class="span2">
       <a href="#editroomtypeModal" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240" alt="">
       <h3>Room 2</h3>
       <p> <%= Forgery(:lorem_ipsum).words(20) %></p>
       </a>
     </li>

     <li class="span2">
        <a href="#editroomModal" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240" alt="">
        <h3>Room 3</h3>
        <p> <%= Forgery(:lorem_ipsum).words(20) %></p>
        </a>
     </li>

     <li class="span2">
        <a href="#managepricesModal" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240" alt="">
        <h3>Room 4</h3>
        <p> <%= Forgery(:lorem_ipsum).words(20) %></p>
        </a>
     </li>

     <li class="span2">
        <a href="#manageextrasModal" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x240" alt="">
        <h3>Room 5</h3>
        <p> <%= Forgery(:lorem_ipsum).words(20) %></p>
        </a>
     </li>


</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a quick guess: i don´t think you need span12 if you hav a row - only if you want to create a special container. But could you post your (section of) code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is possible if you only use the "standard" bootstrap, as the different spans have their own values.

You could either create your own classes - to fit that special need, but you´ll have to calculate your percentages.

Maybe this is a good read:
[bootstrap fluid row width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380384/bootstrap-fluid-row-width)

And another one:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/

```
.my-span5 {
 width: // Should be 20% minus a few something
 margin-left: // do the calculations...
}
```

You also could use javascript to calculate the containing element width, and distribute it evenly to your elements - but you´ll have to keep the margins in mind!

Comment: Bummer, well, I'll look at it and see what I can come up with.