# Twitter bootstrap - less calculation for a fluid grid but with a fixed 30px gutter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fixed, fluid-layout

Is it possible to change the fluid grid calculation in variables.less so that the grid is fluid, but the width of the gutter is fixed?

I've looked at the calculation but am not sure how to remove 30px of width from each fluid span.

Any pointers in the right direction would much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Check for your `_variables.less` file - at the bottom of the file you should be able to edit what you are looking for.

Try these two links, to understand the calculations:

[bootstrap fluid row width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380384/bootstrap-fluid-row-width)

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/09/smart-fixes-for-fluid-layouts/

Hope this helps a bit.

**Edit:**

This might help:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication

Assuming you are using a width of 940px, and a overall gutter of 30px. Doing the calculations 30px of 940px are...

`940 to 100% equals 30 to x%` -> `x = 3.191489361702128` thats your gutter.

if you use 12 cols you have 11 gutters, they use 330px of space, 610px are left for your cols. so each col should be `610px / 12` -> `50,8...px`. Again, do the calculations:

`940 to 100% equals 50,8 to x%` -> `x = 6.170212765957447` for each column.

Of course, do the same for the other two (or more) viewports.

Hope I´m right with this...

**Example of Calculations:**

`(940px / 100) = (30px / x) // multiply with x` ->

`((940px * x) / 100) = (30px) // multiply with 100` ->

`(940px * x) = (3000px) // devide with 940px` ->

`x = (3000px / 940px) // cutting the px`

`x = 3.191489361702128`

Watch out to use the point `.` instead of a comma `,` in your vars.

Comment: Thanks for that but that is the calculation I don't fully understand. Bootstrap seems to take the entire non-fluid calculation and turn it into a percentage. Whereas I need to keep the gutter fixed.

Comment: I also just tried changing `@fluidGridGutterWidth:` to `30px;` but then a `.span6` becomes 186% wide so I feel like I don't really understand the calculation sorry.

Comment: Check the link I added to the answer.

Comment: After reading the links and working on this for several hours, I still don't understand how to accomplish this sorry - my math obviously sucks. Also, I suspect that the bootstrap calculation is not that flexible as I'm needing to split a column in half and that column might be a `span9` - hence using `row-fluid` and using a `span6` but becauase it's nested, the gutters are not the same. Is there a formula that would remove a fixed pixel amount from a percentage?

Comment: You could try to set `$fluidGridGutterWidth: ... ;` manually to your wishes, but keep the original line :) and don´t forget `$fluidGridGutterWidthTablet` and `$fluidGridGutterWidthLarge`.

Comment: Even if you don´t understand the exact calculations, try and play with it to get a feeling.

Comment: Like I said, I spent several hours trying to get a 'feeling' for it and one of the first things I tried was to manually force `@fluidGutterWidth` to be `30px`. But that resulted in a `.span6` being `186%` - why `@fluidGutterWidth` had an effect on the fluid span size, I don't understand as it comes afterwards in the less file. I realise you're trying to get me to figure it out because it's easy - but have you actually tried to use the bootstrap calculations to force a fixed gutter width? If you have figured it out, an explanation might be a bit of a lightbulb moment at this point. Cheers

Comment: Could you use this? If so it would be nice to accept / dismiss the answer.

Comment: Seriously, I don't understand the answer so don't know if I can accept or dismiss sorry. In that second to last line, it still looks like that x = 3.19% instead of a fixed pixel amount? When I get a chance to try them out, I'll definitely accept/dismiss - I always do.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be: add an extra class to your elements like `.my-xtra-margin { margin-left: 30px; }` (be sure to inlucde it after the bootstrap definitions) or directly into your tag as style-definition.

But, i think this will always mess up your layout as the columns need certain percentages of the available width and with a fixed gutter you can endup with `too much`.