# Twitter Bootstrap Responsive width percentage value

Tags: css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, width

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bootstrap fluid row width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380384/bootstrap-fluid-row-width)

I was just looking at the Twitter Bootstrap Responsive CSS and there I saw them using values like

```
.row-fluid .span3 {
    width: 22.92817679558011%;
    *width: 22.87498530621841%;
}
```

How come they have that many digits, I mean it seems to be extremely precise? My guess is that they calculated this value - how?

Comment: Most likely it is calculated by compiling their LESS file.

Comment: If you want to investigate how it's calculated, check out the #grid mixin in mixins.less source code: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L556

Comment: You are looking for this part : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.2.2/less/mixins.less#L628

Comment: @Sherbrow Ah cool, now I understand it! If you post it as an answer I will accept it!